Kunen lemma 7.9, chapter IV.
In Kunens "Set Theory An Introduction to Independence Proofs", lemma 7.9, chapter IV, we are given the following:

Let $G$ be an isomorphism from $A$ to $M$ which respects the $\in$-relation. Then for each formula $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, we have $$\forall x_1,\ldots,x_n \in A[\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^{A} \leftrightarrow \phi(G(x_1),\ldots,G(x_n))^{M}].$$

The proof we are given is really a proof-sketch, which says:

Induction on $\phi$.

Now I presume he means induction on the number of subformulas of $\phi$? I.e. so that we assume by induction that it holds for all formulas less than some subformula length $\ell$. If that is the idea, the cases $\phi = \neg \psi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $\phi = \psi \land \psi'$, together with the "atomic" cases $v_i \in v_j$ or $v_i = v_j$  are clear. But I don't know how to handle the existential quantifier-case. It seems "intuitively" clear that this should hold since $G$ respects $\in$, but I am not sure how to show it.

Constructing a formula in first order logic is a recursive construction. So it is inherently well founded. So we can do induction on the parsing tree.

Dear Asaf: I don't know what a parsing tree is, and I don't understand what you exactly mean is "well-founded". You mean a tree consisting of a "root" $\phi$ and then subformulas of $\phi$ on the next level down, and subformulas of subformulas etc? So you do induction on the $#$ levels of the parsing tree?

See structural induction.

Thanks for the link, although I have to say that it was unenlightening for me, as for the purposes of understanding the proof. That is, I don't see how doing induction on the parsing tree is any different from doing induction on the basic formulas of set theory, which is exactly what I wrote in my post. So I am still left with handling the case $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \exists x \in A\psi(x,x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, as far as I can tell.

Yes, there are two questions here. I'm only answering the first one.

@Ben123 you need to handle unbounded quantifier, not bounded. But the result for $\exists y \varphi(\vec x,y)$ follows pretty readily from the result for $\varphi(\vec x,y)$, which is an induction hypothesis. (You also have a typo in your statement… there need to be some $G$s on the RHS of the $\leftrightarrow$)

Yes, typo fixed, thanks. And yes, it should be unbounded (i.e. $\exists x \psi$).

Hm, how do you mean? If you do induction on the length, as Kunen does in the proof of b) → a) in lemma 7.3 (chap. IV), then surely if $\phi = \exists \psi$ then we can’t say by induction that it follows from $\psi$? If that was the case, then I don’t see why Kunen proceeds as he does in the (above) referenced proof. Please explain what I am missing.

Ops, I see the difference, they actually do induction over the length in the list of formulas $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n$ (possibly expanded to be subformula closed) in lemma 7.3. Tbh not sure how one proves it for the ’’base case” in lemma 7.3.

You say that the base case is clear, as are the steps for negation and conjunction which generate the propositional connectives. Hence only the existential case remains which follows from the considering the universal situation  together with negation.
So assume as structural induction hypothesis that the result holds for $\varphi(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ with exactly all of its free variables shown, where $n \geq 1$. Choose any variable $x_i$ as "next step" as that to which $\forall$ shall apply, so $\phi := \forall x_i \varphi$. I will pick $ i := 1 $ for notational simplicity.
So it is to prove that
$$\forall x_2,\dotsc,x_n \in A[\forall x_1 \in A \varphi(x_1, x_2,\dotsc,x_n)^{A} \leftrightarrow \forall x_1 \in M \varphi(x_1, G(x_2),\dotsc,G(x_n))^{M}].$$
The remainder now follows the standard quantifier procedure. Fix any $x_2, \dotsc, x_n$ from $A$, for these we must prove the inner equivalence. There are two implications there.

In the $\rightarrow$-direction, assume the antecedent, fix $x_1 \in M$ on RHS and use surjectivity of the epsilonisomorphism $G$ and the $\rightarrow$-direction of induction hypothesis.

In the converse direction, mutatis mutandis by swapping directions. In particular, surjectivity becomes functionality of $G$.


This finishes the proof.
